# IIS shutting down my application, returns 503 service unavailable

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, .net

I'm trying to host an API I've done in dotnet core, very standard stuff, acceses and returns data from a Database. I've deployed to IIS before (not in this machine) and it usually goes all right, but not this time.

I've created the WebApp on IIS, launched WACS to create and assign a certificate to it, and ran it, all good, the DNS is pointed correctly and I can retrieved some data from the APIs, however, a few requests later I get this:

**The service is unavailable.**

Well, that's odd, the application is able to work perfectly fine in Kestrel where I just execute it and the cmd windows popups saying it's hosting the app, but as soon as I move it to IIS all hell breaks loose and after a few retries it seems to fail.

I've checked the Event Viewer and this is what's happening:

[image]

Ok great, the App seems to have been started successfully.

A few moments later this happens:

[image]

Wait what? Why is IIS trying to shutdown the application? It works just fine when running the exe in Kestrel-only mode.

What I've done:

I've gone to the settings and changed these:

[image]

I've disabled Rapid-Fail protection in fear that it would be some execeptions that are turning it off.

Doesn't seem to be it... It still dies after a few requests.

I've added this user to the folder's permissions:

[image]

And this is the only app running on this IIS machine:
[image]

And the test connection is telling me this:

[image]

Could this be the issue? If it is why would it be able to serve a few requests and then try to shut itself down?

Can anyone help me? I've never has an issue where IIS is trying to shutdown its own applications.

PS: The Application logs tell me that it's just shutting down:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: D:\IIS Root\RVGL API\
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
```

And the IIS logs just show me the requests, it's serving a couple of 200s and then just 503s.

Edit:
I created a virtual machine on another computer and sent over the files to it, exact same thing happened. I'm stumped.